# Amazon Textract not reading click Checkbox field

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, checkbox, amazon-textract

I am trying to read the attached pdf file using textract but  it is not reading the checkboxes as key value pair fields. It is only reading them as rawdata.  For example, I am interested in the value of the question 10a on page #3. I am expecting the key to be " 10a. Per: (Choose only one)*" and the value to be the checkbox click value.  But it is reading this only as raw text and I can not find if 10a is clicked or unclicked.

Did any one encounter this issue before? Can you please let me know

I have attached AWS textract image screenshots and PDF link

[image]

[The pdf file](https://lca-dev.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Certified_LCA.pdf)

Comment: did you find the answer to this? I had this issue a long time ago. Textract does have a way of detecting checked fields.

Comment: no yet , Do u have any other solution#Ninad

Answer (score 1):

The UI actually does not show this to you but you will see it in the API response if you download it under SELECTION_ELEMENTS

Comment: It's interesting their UI is so garbage at processing the results.